# JavaScript link not sending to correct href

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I'm having problems with a JS link.

I have the following code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('province_aw').addEvent('change', function() {

        var index = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        var b = document.getElementById("choice_2").value;

        var link  = "index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=listSpecific-3&id_province="+index+"&id_ch="+b;
        document.getElementById('link1').href = "index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=listSpecific-3&id_province="+index+"&id_ch="+b;
    });
});
```

with this link:

```
<a class="jcepopup" id="link1" href="" rel="{handler:'iframe'}"> <input type='button' name='prueba' id='prueba' value='...' /> </a>
```

The code is actually changing the link of the < a > tag, however, when I click on the button, nothing happens, it keeps sending me to the original href (which is the homepage).

Answer (score 0):

You should use href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: Tsikon I just used your suggestion in the < a > tag, changing < a class="jcepopup" id="link1" href="" rel=" {handler:'iframe'} " > into < a class="jcepopup" id="link1" href="javascript:void(0); " rel="{handler:'iframe'}" > but to no effect, it keeps changing the link but when i click on it, nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: Aren't you linking to your home page by linking to index.php?

Comment: no, when i try the link that generates in a separate tab it's actually working, but not when i load it there.

Comment: when you right-click on the button and select "open link in a new tab" displays what i want to show, but if click directly is not working...

Comment: No, it's supposed to be that way. If you read the whole link you'll see that the actual link goes to a plugin (Chronofroms), but if you click it it would only open a new blank iframe